# From ERD to Django model and schemas

Tags: python, django, django-models, erd

[image]

I am confused here to convert this ERD into django models/schemas.
Can anyone help me out there?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's an ERD. You should probably read about that before asking here.

Comment: so do you know how to convert it to django models?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but you need to create an app using python manage.py startapp and then in the models.py file of the app you need to define classes (models) which represent the entities in your ER diagram. So in this case you'd need to define the classes OrderItem, Product, ProductFeature, and Order.

Next thing you need to add attributes and relationships to the classes (models) e.g.:

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    introduction_date = DateTimeField()
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)

class Order(models.Model):
    order_date = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ...

class ProductFeature(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    product_feature = models.ForeignKey(ProductFeature, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

Note, Django creates autoincrement id's automatically unless you have changed this behaviour.

I also highly recommend you do the tutorial offered in the Django documentation; it's pretty helpful to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas for the help. but what about subtypes which are located within the ER diagram?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly they represent (I've never seen that kind of notation of an ER diagram) but, I think they are entities with a one-to-one relationship to the main entity they are inside of. If that's the case, you'd also create classes like class Color, class ProductQuality etc. and then inside the classes you add a foreign key attribute linking them to the entity they are inside of in the diagram. Are you making an online store from scratch? I'm also doing the same and have taken a different approach to deal with products with different sizes, colors etc. which may be more efficient.

Comment: thanks, Thomas for the help. yes, I am confused about the entities that are inside of the entity. and Yes I am developing an inventory management system. I would like to you help more to elaborate it so that I can proceed to the next procedure.

Comment: product_feature = models.ForeignKey(ProductFeature, on_delete=models.PROTECT) and why you added on_delete=models.PROTECT?

Comment: Do you have to specifically use that model or are you free to do something else? I think the ones inside the other entity are also just separate entities. You just make them like you would with any other entity i.e. using a class and then you link them to the entity their located inside of by using a foreign key. I think they did that just to save space when drawing the ERD. But I could be wrong; I have never encountered an ERD drawn like that and I'm just making a speculation based on what makes the most sense.

Comment: I just did models.PROTECT so that when a product feature is deleted, the order item wouldn't be deleted. In fact, models.PROTECT would cause Django to refuse to delete any product feature linked to an order item. You can choose to do things like models.CASCADE etc. But I don't think I can give as clear and detailed an explanation as you would find in the Django documentation.

Comment: Thomas, You're right. because I have read in the documentation that the entity inside an entity is subtype of its super type so I think those are also entities.